# How can I get rainyday.js to use a CSS background image as it's background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a basic website with a full sized, fixed background set with CSS. I want to implement rainyday.js over the top of everything in my whole site (including the text).

Currently, the best I can do is getting rainyday.js to overlay another background image over the top and rain in that small section. It is creating another 'background' and using that instead.

It seems it is possible [here](https://github.com/maroslaw/rainyday.js/issues/95), however I don't understand how you are supposed to do it.

[This is the rainy day code.](https://github.com/maroslaw/rainyday.js)

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">

    <title>Safe House</title>

    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>



<body>


    <div id="yes">
        <div id="maindiv">
            Safe House
        </div>

        <div id="secondarydiv">
            <p>noun</p>

            <p>1.</p>

            <p>a dwelling or building whose conventional appearance makes it a
            safe or</p>

            <p>inconspicuous place for hiding, taking refuge, or carrying on
            clandestine activities.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coming+Soon);


#maindiv {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Coming Soon', sans-serif;
      font-style: italic;
      color: white;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 10em;
      font-weight: 700;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#secondarydiv{

    font-family: 'Coming Soon', sans-serif;
      font-style: italic;
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      font-size: 1.5em; /*font size of main headings*/
      font-weight: 700;
      text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      margin-left: 300px;
}

#yes {
    margin-top: 150px;
}


body { 
  background: url("images/bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

p {
    margin: 0;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Author still working on it, see https://github.com/maroslaw/rainyday.js/issues/95, you can discuss with others in that issue ticket, even join the progress to add this feature!